# Intercept observables before subscription callback

Tags: rxjs

I am using the following code to make get request:

```
    makeGetReq$(url:string):Observable{
        let getReqObservable;
        getReqObservable = this.httpClient.get(url) //code for making get request
        return getReqObservable
    }
```

The problem is sometimes my backend might return `{error:true, message}` with status code 200. (I know thats weird).In that case I want to intecept `getReqObservable` and not allow its subscription callback to run.

**image.component.ts**

```
    makeGetReq$(url:string):Observable{
         let getReqObservable;
         getReqObservable = this.httpClient.get(url)//code for making get request
         return getReqObservable
                    .do((value)=>{
                       if(value.error){
                       //do not allow it to propagate further
                      })

      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would probably be `filter`.

> Filter items emitted by the source Observable by only emitting those that satisfy a specified predicate.

It would look like this:

```
return getReqObservable
    .filter(value => !value.error)
```

It was pointed out, that you lose the notification completely if you just filter out the error case. There is of course the option to create a RxJS error notification with `throwError`, but it is also possible to just subscribe to the same source observable a second time with a different filter condition.

Be careful however to not call the backend twice, e.g. by using `share`.

Answer (score 1):

You **should** propagate it further, but as an error rather than an event (i.e. do just like if your backend did the right thing and returned an error response):

```
makeGetReq$(url: string): Observable<Something> {
  return this.httpClient.get<Something>(url).pipe(
    mergeMap(value => value.error ? throwError(value) : of(value))
  );       
}
```

Otherwise, the calling method has no way to know that an error occurred, and thus can't execute the callbacks it might have registered for errors.

Comment: Don't know if you gave me -1, but converting the server error to a RxJS error is not the only solution for handling errors... It is equally legitimate to just subscribe a second time to the error case (i.e. changing the filter predicate). OP didn't ask how to create a RxJS error notification...

Comment: Subscribe a second time would send a second HTTP request. So no, that's a terrible idea, too.

Comment: That is way more inconvenient than just throwing. And it makes it impossible to encapsulate the logic in the service, where it belongs.

Comment: I'd probably also use error notifcation, but OP asked... : "do not allow it to propagate further" and error is a propagation. But your solution is probably better if one wanted to handle the error explicitely.

Comment: My guess is that he actually wanted to ask how to handle the situation, and how to avoid propagating it *as an event*. I someone asks for how to do something he shouldn't do, I prefer telling him how to solve the problem in a correct way.

Comment: Thanks. Can I use map operator as well? like:  `.map((value:any)=>{
        if(value && value.error){
          this.showErrorMessageForErrorTrue(value);
          return throwError(value)
        }else {
          return value;
        }
      })`

Comment: No. map() is supposed to transform a value into another value. Not a value into an observable. That would get you an Observable<Observable<Something>>.